# Bypass Rack::Cache for requests coming from a CDN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack, amazon-cloudfront, rack-cache

I have a Rails 3.2 app, deployed to heroku.  I use caching with [Rack::Cache](https://github.com/rtomayko/rack-cache/) and Amazon CloudFront.

For Requests that are served via CloudFront (assets, mostly), the caching layer with Rack::Cache is redundant and I'd rather not use it there (memcached on heroku is *expensive*)

What is a good way to skip Rack::Cache for these requests?

Answer (score 0):

This blog post helped me http://jackchu.com/blog/2011/09/20/rails-asset-pipeline-content-delivery-networks-and-rack-cache/

I turned rack cache off completely with:

```
config.middleware.delete Rack::Cache
```

He also has another suggestion to replace rack cache with rack static for assets only, which still leaves rack cache in place for other requests.